# AngularJS : Why parsing data does not display on view?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to parse `json` file and want to display on view. I am able to display data on console but I am not able to display on view .I am using ng-repeat. But, it is not working.

Also, I tried **$scope.$apply** but it gives error and digest cycle already running but data is not display, why?

Below is my plunker Link:

http://plnkr.co/edit/uyyhxex5gubzTJSZipV0?p=preview

```
HelloWorldService.doWork().then(function(data){
     console.log("data received to Ctrl");

    $scope.data=data.employees;
     $scope.hide();
    // $scope.$apply();

   })
```

Comment: why using ng-controller on body element. dont you need ion-view to display data ?

Comment: it not matter why making POC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.data = JSON.parse(data).employees
```

Answer (score 1):

In the service you should convert String to Json by using `angular.fromJson(e.data)` and it works just fine. See the working example

http://plnkr.co/edit/J3p13z99gRBlHmuSal1c?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` is a string. You need to parse it with `angular.fromJson` before you can use it.

```
HelloWorldService.doWork().then(function(data){
     console.log("data received to Ctrl");

    $scope.data=angular.fromJson(data).employees;
     $scope.hide();
    // $scope.$apply();

   })
```